# cannot convert from 'object' to 'string'

Tags: c#

I have the following method:

```
       private string Val(object val)
       {
         int vId;
         bool isNumeric = Int32.TryParse(val, out vId);
         return string.Empty;
        }
```

I get the following compile time error:

```
           cannot convert from 'object' to 'string'
```

Comment: Did you try a cast?  IE `TryParse((string)val, outvID)`.  Why are you passing a generic object in the first place?

Comment: What do you expect as result? It is very unclear from your sample what you trying to do. Also quite obvious what fails, but I guess you know that object is not string too... So please clarify your actual goal.

Comment: `TryParse` expects `string`, you're passing `object` instead and wondering why compiler is not happy with that? What's unclear in that error?

Comment: Whoever up-voted the question please clarify what code supposed to do.

Comment: All we have so far is a statement, not a question please clarify

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
       private string Val(string val)
       {
         int vId;
         bool isNumeric = Int32.TryParse(val, out vId);
         return string.Empty;
        }
```

Try parse assumes a string not object, so you have to update the data type of the input.

Answer (score 2):

`TryParse(String, Int32)` require first parameter a string not a object. convert object to string then try to parse it to int

Try like this

```
bool isNumeric = Int32.TryParse(val.ToString(), out vId);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try passing a string in as your first argument. Currently, you have `val` set as an object when `TryParse` expects a string. You could cast the object to a string (`val.toString()`) but more than likely you'll want to just send a string through to start with.

If you'd like to look at the code around this a little further I'll be glad to help, but looking at the few lines of code in your question it seems that you should just be sending through a string in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

TryParse(String, Int32) require first parameter a string not a object. convert object to string then try to parse it to int

Try like this

bool isNumeric = Int32.TryParse(val.ToString(), out vId);

Answer (score -1):

If you are trying to find if object is numeric you could use `is` operator.

```
 eg: bool isInt = o is int // Assuming o is object
```

you could create a method that checks if an object is numeric by having others as well like :
     o is int || o is float || and so on.

Regarding TryParse, it requires of type String (in visual studio intellisense will also tell you). So, either change parameter object to string or convert object to string.